# Parse a varchar2 Column Value

Tags: oracle

I want to remove a piece of a string from a particular table's column.  The string I wish to remove is the &expires and everything after it but leave everything before the &expires the same. Is there a way to accomplish with the update statement or is a stored procedure needed?

Table column value is:

**Starting Value:**    `DAABq3J65GvwBABbWdkFOnpCj2mEA1lMonZBZADcTYJR6QuLPUlfZBtMyoEl4x2JXQ49cOzjZAStQxWNOgrurtnMNIw04bmOcQ4SsrjuPKH4AZBBBAf8ZBjWhs8BM52aC0OpnPGzjm6V2x50qk6wboT&expires=5183999`

**Desired Ending Value:**

```
DAABq3J65GvwBABbWdkFOnpCj2mEA1lMonZBZADcTYJR6QuLPUlfZBtMyoEl4x2JXQ49cOzjZAStQxWNOgrurtnMNIw04bmOcQ4SsrjuPKH4AZBBBAf8ZBjWhs8BM52aC0OpnPGzjm6V2x50qk6wboT
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
update table set column = regexp_replace(column, '&'||'expires=.*$')
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me.  When running the update statement you provided, I get prompted with a dialog that asks me to enter a substitution variable for EXPIRES:  I've tried entering a space or nothing at all and the updates don't work.  The script output is:  old:update external_link set access_token = regexp_replace(access_token, '&expires=.*$')
new:update external_link set access_token = regexp_replace(access_token, '=.*$')
519 rows updated.

Comment: @c12: try replacing `'&'` with `CHR(38)`.

Comment: neither the  regexp_replace(column, '&'||'expires=.*$') or the  regexp_replace(column, CHR(38)||'expires=.*$') worked and the string remained the same.  No errors.  Both of these did not prompt me for the substitution value though, so that's good.

Comment: the column is a VARCHAR2(400)

Comment: @c12 It works here: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3794/1) Maybe you can show your table schema and the code you ran?

Comment: I must have had a typo as it works after I carefully reviewed it in my oracle sql window.